# C++ overloading << error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I am hoping to get some help with an error I am getting - I have searched similar questions which havent really gave me what I'm after. A code snippet is listed below:

```
class NewSelectionDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:

  class CProductListBox
  {
    public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b);
  };
   ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,  const CProductListBox& b)
  {
        std::cout << o.m_lstEclispeProducts;
        return o;
  }
```

I have a list box that contains a number of strings - these can vary depending on other drop down boxes selected.  I want to what is in this box to a file as well as what the user selects from the drop downs that popluate it.  Howvever I am getting the following error (I am developing in VS 2008).

> error C2804: binary `'operator <<'` has too many parameters
>   error C2333: `'NewSelectionDlg::operator <<'` : error in function declaration; skipping function body

I am not sure why as i belive the syntax of overloading the operator is OK - can anyone see anything I have done stupid or may have missed - Many Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 5):

Just define it outside of class definition or define it in subclass when declaring friendship:

```
class NewSelectionDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:

  class CProductListBox
  {
    public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b);
  };

// (...) Rest of NewSelectionDlg
}; 

ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, const NewSelectionDlg::CProductListBox& b)
{
    // Did you meant:
    return o << b.m_lstEclispeProducts;
}
```

or

```
class NewSelectionDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:

  class CProductListBox
  {
    public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b)
    {
        // Did you meant:
        return o << b.m_lstEclispeProducts;
    }
  };

// (...) Rest of NewSelectionDlg
};
```

Comment: Hi Pawel - Thanks for your help - I posted up another query if you can help - Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`operator <<` must not be a member function. The first argument must be `std::ostream`; in your code, the first (implicit) argument is the `this` pointer, i.e. an object of type `NewSelectionDlg*`.

You need to implement `operator <<` as a free function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the overloaded `operator<<` outside the definition of `NewSelectionDlg` and scope `CProductListBox` accordingly.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const NewSelectionDlg::CProductListBox& b)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for all the suggestions Guys - I will work through these and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Also, should it be a `b` rather than an `o` in the <<:

```
    std::cout << o.m_lstEclispeProducts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with your second solution.

```
class NewSelectionDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:

  class CProductListBox
  {
    public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b)
    {

       return o << b.m_lstEclispeProducts;
    }
  };
```

I am still getting an error - error C2039: 'm_lstEclispeProducts' : is not a member of 'NewSelectionDlg::CProductListBox'

I am not sure as to why this is because part of the NewSelectionDlg class contains this code (relevant line in bold) - if you have any further help/suggestions it would be a great help.  Thanks

```
// Dialog Data

//{{AFX_DATA(NewSelectionDlg)

  enum { IDD = IDD_NEW_SELECTION };

  CButton   m_btnMessageBoard;

  CButton m_btnMoreInfo;

  CComboBox m_cmbOpenDocuments;

  CButton m_btnOk;

  CButton m_btnStateApprovals;

  CComboBox m_cmbProductType;

///  CListBox  m_lstSalesConcepts;

  CButton   m_chkObjectiveWizard;

  **CProductListBox  m_lstEclipseProducts;**
```

Comment: It's because you `m_lstEclispeProducts` it's member of `NewSelectionDlg` and not `NewSelectionDlg::CProductListBox`. How you use this code? Consider adding a variable to `NewSelectionDlg::CProductListBox` storing `m_lstEclispeProducts` from object that you want to print.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, but a slightly different tool. Trying to build a discussion based on answers is not a good idea, as the answers are reordered in each page reload. If you want to write a comment to an answer, just use the comment box. In this particular case, you should probably create a different question, since the problem now is unrelated to the original one. I understand that this might not be obvious for someone starting though :)

Comment: Now, on your particular issue, in C++ inner classes don't have access to outer classes, so if you want to access the outer class member, you should offer that functionality at the outer class level.

Comment: Thanks David - just new to the forum - will take note for future.  Pawel - I believe I may have to do this slightly differently - there is a seperate header file for CProductListBox- //CProductListBox
class CProductListBox : public CListBox
{DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CProductListBox)
public:
CProductListBox();
virtual ~CProductListBox();

protected:
 DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
    virtual void MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct);
};  Would it be best to add the overload << code to here to get this to work correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use the declaration:

friend void foo();

what you are doing is declaring a function in the enclosing namespace scope.

```
namespace name {
   struct outer {
      struct inner {
         friend void foo(); // declares name::foo
      };
   };
   void foo() {} // defines it
}
```

The same goes for operators.